# Spreadsheet Dashboard in odoo 16

Tags: odoo-16

How to show and hide graph and pivot tables in odoo 16 spreadsheet based dashboard with help of filter and condition.

I have tried  to  make changes in json file of the dashboards but its not reflecting.